# HP Laser Jet 2035 printer problems with 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, laserjet

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.
It's all fine, except that my printer, a HP Laser Jet 2035, does not work.
I keep getting messages about drivers, but I either can't find them or can't download them?

The printer was working great in 16.04, so I am not sure what advantage I now have!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We need more information to answer your question. How is your printer connected to the Ubuntu 18.04 computer, by USB, by Ethernet cable via a router, by WiFi, or by pure magic? We cannot stand over your shoulder and read the message when you state "I keep getting messages about drivers..." Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1082381/edit) your **question above** and add more details. Copy and paste output and error messages where possible, such as from Terminals, or take a screenshot by pressing Alt+PrintScreen. Upload the picture in imgur.com and link in question.